# Reading csv file in chunks for processing

Tags: c#, .net, csv, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have a .csv file with 100 000 records with five columns in it. I am reading it line by line and storing it in a remote database .

Previously, I was following a performance oriented approach. I was reading the .csv file line by line and in the same transaction I was opening the connection to database and closing it. This was taking a serious performance overhead.
For just writing 10 000 lines, it took one hour.

```
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Data.csv")) 
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
            {
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
                parser.Delimiters = new[] { " " };
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    //Open a connection to a database 
                    //Write the data from the .csv file line by line
                    //Close the connection
                 }
             }
```

Now I have changed the approach. For testing purpose I have taken a .csv file with 10 000 lines and after reading all the 10 000 lines, I am making one connection to database and writing it there.

Now, the only issue is:
I want to read first 10 000 lines and write it, similarly read the next 10 000 lines and write it,

```
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Data.csv")) 
                using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
```

but the above two lines will read the entire file . I don’t want to read it completely.
Is there any way to read the .csv file chunk by chunk of 10 000 lines each?

Answer (score 8):

Try below code it reads data from csv chunk by chunk

```
 IEnumerable<DataTable> GetFileData(string sourceFileFullName)
    {            

        int chunkRowCount = 0;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
        {
            string line = null;
            //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {                                                  
               chunkRowCount++;
               var chunkDataTable = ; ////Code for filling datatable or whatever   

                if (chunkRowCount == 10000)
                {
                    chunkRowCount = 0;
                    yield return chunkDataTable;
                    chunkDataTable = null;
                }
            }
        }
        //return last set of data which less then chunk size
        if (null != chunkDataTable)                           
            yield return chunkDataTable;            
    }
```